# Using Filemerge how to you get to see the lower pane. The one with the results in?

Tags: filemerge

You know, you do a clean install and the pane at the bottom has disappeared. 
I loved that pane.

Comment: Pouring a glass of fine whiskey on the floor for that pane.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

See that little dot. Click on it and you can pull the window into view. 
Life is better now.

Comment: Drinking that same glass of fine whiskey off the floor. Thanks!