# How do I tell FileMerge to remember my settings about the bottom pane?

Tags: osx-yosemite, filemerge, gitbox

A few years ago, someone asked [how they could get the bottom pane in FileMerge back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710071/using-filemerge-how-to-you-get-to-see-the-lower-pane-the-one-with-the-results-i). The answer was that FileMerge remembered your settings, and if you'd accidentally resized the bottom pane to take up no space at all, it would faithfully be invisible again next time you opened FileMerge.

Yosemite has changed that behaviour, and I want it back. I have no interest in the bottom pane. It takes up space that I'd rather have for the before and after left and right panes. And every time I click on a changed file in Gitbox I have to resize that annoying bottom pane out of the window before I can look at the diff properly.

Any ideas? "No, they've broken FileMerge but this other free Mac OS X tool does what you want and Gitbox can launch it with only a minimum of fuss" would be an acceptable alternate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since my version control tool uses a shell script behind
the scenes to open FileMerge, I was able to use the setting described here to hide the merge pane:
   https://ftangftang.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/filemerge-bug/

It's not an ideal solution, but was hoping it would 
suffice until Apple fixes the problem.

My updated git-diff-cmd.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
defaults write com.apple.FileMerge MergeHeight 0
/usr/bin/opendiff "$2" "$5" -merge "$1"
```

Comment: That doesn't last, though. Not every time, but occasionally FileMerge goes back to its previous setting.

Comment: I inserted the defaults setting call into my git-diff-cmd.sh script. The settings are set on every diff call. I don't use Gitbox, but a quick tryout with it shows that it doesn't use the git-dff-cmd.sh script like other tools do. Perhaps you can fashion a workaround?